# Is java.util.Optional<T> map function thread-safe ? If yes, How can I test it?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, option-type

I do not have a lot of experience in Java and I have not used java.util.Optional map function in production code. However, I need to use it for implementing a use case and the first thought which came to my mind, is this thread-safe ? As long as the mapping function in the argument is thread-safe, can we assume the overall operation will be thread safe ?
How can I test this ?

I appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: It is as thread-safe as the function you pass in.

Comment: Why do you want to test a built-in method? Can you trust that the developers already did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Optional.map` is as thread-safe as the function you pass in as the parameter. Essentially all it does is:

```
public <V> Optional<V> map(Function<? super T, ? extends V> fn) {
  if (isPresent()) {
    V value = fn.apply(get());
    if (value != null) {
      return Optional.of(value);
    }
  }
  return Optional.absent();
}
```

Since `Optional` is immutable (meaning that `isPresent()` and `get()` always return the same value, and the value returned by `get()` will have been safely published), the only thing here that could possibly be thread-unsafe is the call `fn.apply(get())`.

---

> As long as the mapping function in the argument is thread-safe, can we assume the overall operation will be thread safe ? How can I test this ?

With great difficulty. You can't really write a test to prove that something is thread-safe, because you can't prove the reason you didn't observe thread-unsafety is because of the correctness of your code, or because your test simply didn't do anything that would exercise the thread-unsafety.

You can only do this by reasoning about the code with respect to the properties of the Java Memory Model.

Answer (score 0):

In a couple of situations I have been able to demonstrate the thread-unsafety of a class or method by spawning two or more threads calling the method repeatedly until one either gets a wrong result or an exception. As Andy Turner already said, even if the method is thread-unsafe, there is no guarantee that your test will reveal it. In some situations it will in practice.

Since `Optional` is immutable, it is thread-safe. So in this case your test will not show anything (unless the function you pass to `map()` is thread-unsafe). So you will have to decide yourself whether that leaves you more assured than you already were.